# How to open pdf file inside android browser?

Tags: android, pdf, browser

I have html page with link on local pdf file. I want to open this pdf file inside browser(chrome, opera, dolphin) without active internet connection. May you known plugin, that can to open pdf file(without download) inside browser or method or something else?

Comment: Show us your R&D you have done so far. Have you tried to search on Stackoverflow itself?

Comment: I'm looking for a second week. But docs.google not suitable (need active connection), a set of plug-ins(perfect viewer pdf, kingsoft office e.t) do not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the native browser present on Android devices not support this type of file. Let's see if in the 4.0+ we will be able to do that.

Comment: What types of files are supprted?

Answer (score 2):

A solution I used once is to open them with Google Docs.

```
_webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ url);
```

Comment: without active connection to internet

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
CustomWebView webView = (CustomWebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + yourUrl);
```

Make CustomWebView class as below:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    private Context context;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setWebSetting();
    }

    private void setWebSetting() {
        WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(false);
        setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    }

    class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null,
                    context.getString(R.string.msg_please_wait));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: without active connection to internet

Comment: You need active connection to internet for using this approach.